# Symfony 4 sqlite database creation for test environment

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

For integration test purpose I am trying to create an sqlite db for test env but when I run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test` I get errors that tables already exists. I suppose because it is not really creating a new test db but going on the existing db.

Looks like it is not reading from env.test.

I created a `doctrine.yaml` in config/test like this:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
    url: 'sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/test.sqlite'
```

What I am missing to create an sqlite test db?

Strange thing I get in the error:

```
In PDOConnection.php line 90:

 SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'user_menu' already exists
```

Why SQL? Should not be IT for sqlite, am I right?

In config/packages/doctrine.yaml, I have:

```
parameters:
# Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
# This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
# environment variables are not available yet.
# You should not need to change this value.
env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    connections:
            gui:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_GUI_URL)%'
            upv6:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_UPV6_URL)%'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes:  true # <- change to true
    proxy_dir:            '%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
    proxy_namespace:      Proxies

    entity_managers:
        gui:
            connection: gui
            mappings:
                Gui:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Gui'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Gui'
                    alias: Gui
        upv6:
            connection: upv6
            mappings:
                Upv6:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Upv6'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Upv6'
                    alias: Upv6
```

My doctrine settings:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    connections:
        gui:
            driver: pdo_mysql
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
            default_table_options:
                charset: utf8mb4
                collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_GUI_URL)%'
            host: localhost
            port: null
            user: root
            password: null
            logging: true
            profiling: true
            options: {  }
            mapping_types: {  }
            slaves: {  }
            shards: {  }
        upv6:
            driver: pdo_mysql
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
            default_table_options:
                charset: utf8mb4
                collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_UPV6_URL)%'
            host: localhost
            port: null
            user: root
            password: null
            logging: true
            profiling: true
            options: {  }
            mapping_types: {  }
            slaves: {  }
            shards: {  }
        default:
            driver: pdo_sqlite
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            host: localhost
            port: null
            user: root
            password: null
            logging: true
            profiling: true
            options: {  }
            mapping_types: {  }
            default_table_options: {  }
            slaves: {  }
            shards: {  }
    default_connection: default
    types: {  }
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    proxy_dir: /var/www/symfony/var/cache/test/doctrine/orm/Proxies
    proxy_namespace: Proxies
    entity_managers:
        gui:
            connection: gui
            mappings:
                Gui:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: /var/www/symfony/src/Entity/Gui
                    prefix: App\Entity\Gui
                    alias: Gui
                    mapping: true
            query_cache_driver:
                type: array
                namespace: null
                cache_provider: null
            metadata_cache_driver:
                type: array
                namespace: null
                cache_provider: null
            result_cache_driver:
                type: array
                namespace: null
                cache_provider: null
            class_metadata_factory_name: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory
            default_repository_class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
            auto_mapping: false
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.default
            quote_strategy: doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default
            entity_listener_resolver: null
            repository_factory: doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory
            hydrators: {  }
            filters: {  }
        upv6:
            connection: upv6
            mappings:
                Upv6:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: /var/www/symfony/src/Entity/Upv6
                    prefix: App\Entity\Upv6
                    alias: Upv6
                    mapping: true
            query_cache_driver:
                type: array
                namespace: null
                cache_provider: null
            metadata_cache_driver:
                type: array
                namespace: null
                cache_provider: null
            result_cache_driver:
                type: array
                namespace: null
                cache_provider: null
            class_metadata_factory_name: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory
            default_repository_class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
            auto_mapping: false
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.default
            quote_strategy: doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default
            entity_listener_resolver: null
            repository_factory: doctrine.orm.container_repository_factory
            hydrators: {  }
            filters: {  }
    resolve_target_entities: {  }
```

Comment: what is in `/config/packages/doctrine.yml`?

Comment: @fyrye I have updated the post.

Comment: Ok, so your additional `config/packages/test/doctrine.yml` won't remove the main configuration settings, but works more like `array_merge` does and augments the existing values. Your config should result in both the `config/packages/doctrine.yml` connections of `gui` and `upv6` and the `config/packages/test/doctrine.yml` of `default` You should be able to view all of the settings by running `php bin/console debug:config doctrine` post the result here.

Comment: Don't forget to add `--env=test` to `php bin/console debug:config doctrine` Symfony always defaults to `--env=dev` So `php bin/console --env=test debug:config doctrine`

Comment: where shoud  I set this?

Comment: I have ran php bin/console debug:config doctrine --env=test and I get finally the sqllite connection, I have updated the post

Comment: @fyrye as you can see now there is a default connection with pdo lite. How can I run it using: docker-compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test  ?

Comment: Added an answer, would need to know more about how you are expecting to use the `sqlite` connection in relation to your entity managers, But my answer can easily be updated to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, really good answer. Very helpful. I will accept it. Now I get sqllite driver not found. Can you help me on this too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193569/discussion-between-stefano-maglione-and-fyrye).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the way Symfony merges configuration files.

`/config/packages/*.yml` > `/config/packages/<env>/*.yml`

This results in all of the connections and entity managers defined in `packages/doctrine.yml` being added to your `packages/test/doctrine.yml`

To see the merged configuration settings Symfony will use, run:

```
php bin/console --env=test debug:config doctrine
```

Because of this running `bin/console --env=test doctrine:schema:create` will attempt to create the schema for **ALL** of the **entity managers** present in the resulting configuration.

To resolve the issue you will need to segregate your environment configs into `prod`, `test`, and `dev` or alternatively use `.env.test` to change the URLs used by Syfmony.

Depending on how you need to access your entity managers

### Example

> This is only an **example** of how to segregate the environment
>   configurations, be sure to change any needed values for your application
>   requirements

**config/packages/doctrine.yml**

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes:  true # <- change to true
        proxy_dir:            '%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
        proxy_namespace:      Proxies
```

**config/packages/dev/doctrine.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        connections:
                gui:
                    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                    server_version: '5.7'
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    default_table_options:
                        charset: utf8mb4
                        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_GUI_URL)%'
                upv6:
                    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                    server_version: '5.7'
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    default_table_options:
                        charset: utf8mb4
                        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_UPV6_URL)%'        
        entity_managers:
            gui:
                connection: gui
                mappings:
                    Gui:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Gui'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Gui'
                        alias: Gui
            upv6:
                connection: upv6
                mappings:
                    Upv6:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Upv6'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Upv6'
                        alias: Upv6
```

**config/packages/test/doctrine.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        url: 'sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/test.sqlite'

    #DEFINE THE ENTITY MANAGERS TO USE THE default CONNECTION
    #orm:
        #since the connections are not the same
        #you need to define your entity managers here...
        #entity_managers:
     #      gui:
     #          connection: default #<---- NOTICE DEFAULT and not gui 
     # (not sure what entity managers are needed for sqlite)
     #...
```

**config/packages/prod/doctrine.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: '../dev/doctrine.yaml' }

doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false #<-- change to false
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        query_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
        result_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.result_cache_provider
     #...
```